# Accessing an object for jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

This is a small part of the JSON that i use (which has the same structure)..so i need to get all the ship names from GOD and LEG and use them at JQuery autocomplete

```
{
  "GOD": {
  "name": "This is a test",
  "code": "GOD",
        "ships": [
            {
                "layout": "normal",
                "type": "Destroyer",
                "name": "Ship George"
            },
            {
                "layout": "normal",
                "type": "Airship",
                "name": "The strong one"
            }
        ]
    },
    "LEG": {
        "name": "Limited God",
        "code": "LEG",
        "ships": [
            {
                "layout": "normal",
                "type": "bad",
                "name": "Blair witch"
            },
            {
                "layout": "normal",
                "type": "the worst",
                "name": "New era"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem is that i want to display in autocomplete only the "ships" names.
The code that i use for autocomplete is :

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term: request.term,
            },
            type: 'Get',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: true,
            url: 'all.json',
            success: function (data) {
                var array = $.map(data, function (set) {
                    return {
                        label: set.name,
                        value: set.name
                    }
                });

                //call the filter here
                response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(array, request.term));
            },
            error: function (data) {
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    open: function () { },
    close: function () { },
    focus: function (event, ui) { },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $( "#card" ).val( ui.item.label );
        //$( "#description" ).html( ui.item.text );
        $( "#multiverseid" ).val( ui.item.multi );
        $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=" + ui.item.multi + "&type=card" );
    }
});
```

With that code above i get as autocomplete the values of : GOD and the LEG

if i change the line to :

```
var array = $.map(data.GOD.ships, function (set) {
```

then i get all the ships specifically of the GOD

What i need is to get autocomplete suggestions with all the ship names of both GOD and LEG (and others "GODS" and "LEGS" that there are)

Comment: just a thought, what if you put data.GOD.ships and then in the same array data.LEG.ships that way array will be populated with both value....

Comment: The thought is not bad, but how will i implement that inside JQuery autocomplete, using $.map or other function...

Comment: what value request.term holds?

Comment: It's the value in the text field (while user typing, autocomplete functions)...

Comment: I am putting code which is just to let you know what  I am thinking, its not tested you can try. I will remove it as an answer. But I am sure there will be a better way.

Comment: 1) It displays data only from the data.LEG.ships..2) I need the .GOD. , .LEG. to be also filtered/pulled automatically somehow, as there are hundreds...

Comment: I have updated the answer for first point. Did not get the second point. As of now it will only show name for both GOD and SHIP in autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Success could be like this :**

```
  var array = $.map(data.GOD.ships, function (set) {
                        return {
                            label: set.name,
                            value: set.name
                        }
                    });
                 var   array1 = $.map(data.LEG.ships, function (set) {
                        return {
                            label: set.name,
                            value: set.name
                        }
                    });
              var outputArray = $.merge(array, array1);                
             console.log(outputArray)
            //call the filter here
            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(outputArray, request.term));
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
```

**EDIT 1:**

```
var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames ( data )
var outputArray;

$.each(keys,function(ele, val){

    var array = $.map(data[val].ships, function (set) {
                        return {
                            label: set.name,
                            value: set.name
                        }
                    });     
      if(ele == 0)
           outputArray = $.merge([], array);
      else{
           outputArray = $.merge(outputArray, array);
       }  
});
response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(outputArray, request.term));
},
error: function (data) {
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
var keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames ( data )
var outputArray;

$.each(keys,function(ele, val){

    var array = $.map(data[val].ships, function (set) {
                        return {
                          label: set.name + "(" +keys[ele] + ")",
                        value: set.name + "(" +keys[ele] + ")"
                        }
                    });     
      if(ele == 0)
           outputArray = $.merge([], array);
      else{
           outputArray = $.merge(outputArray, array);
       }  
});
response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(outputArray, request.term));
},
error: function (data) {
}
```

Comment: works...but now i need to create these arrays and merge them somehow automatically! (as they are hundred and not only 2...)!! Thank you

Comment: do u mean to say there are more keys than just GOD and LEG? or does GOD and LEG have more children's?

Comment: There are more GOD and LEG (about a hundred and more) that have ships inside. So we need for example a loop that will grab this automatically through the json file and create array1,array2,array3 and then merge them with the way above

Comment: need to see the JSON sample could you post a sample; not complete but at least to cover the entire hierarchy?

Comment: it's at the top of this post! It's a sample of the entire json with the same hierarchy

Comment: I doubt why do you have same key GOD or LEG multiple times. that's not correct JSON. see my updated answer to see why..

Comment: There is not the same key...the GOD, LEG have the same structure, so let's say they are : GOD, LEG, HAT, MAP, BET, BOT etc ( unique values each one). All of them have the same structure. The whole JSON file is correct and validated... and all of them have ships inside, where ships have a name...

Comment: got it gimmme a moment

Comment: Works like a charm mate!! Excellent work..really thank you. I have also one question if you can answer me.. if i want to display except the name at the text field (set.name) also the category it belongs, for example : The strong one (GOD) ... any idea? :))

Comment: Excellent mate! Thank youuuu, i will vote up your solution when i go reputation 15, you are just amazing!

Comment: Glad it helped! Cheers!